# not able to install bcrypt module in node js

Tags: node.js

My system details 
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

node -v v6.0.0

npm -v 3.8.6

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.2/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.2-node-v48-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.2 and node@6.0.0 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

Comment: see this link https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/487 . try after updating node

Answer (score 0):

The tar.gz you are trying to download gives a 404.

Try to install bcryct with that : `npm install bcrypt`

Complete install procedure can be found : https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, by first installing the required packages.

1. First I checked the version of my os, using this [command](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/):

   ```
   cat /etc/*-release
   ```
2. Then [updated](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions#ubuntu-and-derivatives---elementary-linux-mint-etc) the libraries by:

   ```
   Sudo NPM install node-gyp -g
   sudo apt-get install Python
   sudo apt-get install make
   sudo apt-get install g+
   ```
3. Then using root permission I again did `NPM install` which installed the bycrypt correctly this time.